# How to trigger display of another chart when bar is clicked in highchart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm using the [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) library. I have a bar chart and want to know how I can trigger the display of another chart. Here is the code for my bar chart:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked bar chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [ "Meat", "Fruit", "Veg" ]
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
        series: [{
        name: 'Yes',
        data: [
            42, 17, 34]
    }, {
        name: 'No',
        data: [
        10,16,38 ]
    }]
});
```

For example in my chart on this [page](http://jsfiddle.net/X65dh/1/) when the user clicks on the 'meat' bar, I'd like to load a pie chart *elsewhere* on the page showing a breakdown of the 'meat' data and likewise for the 'fruit' and 'vegetable' bars.

The drilldown functionality of Highcharts is the closest functionality I found to what I require, the caveat being that the display of the breakdown chart replaces the original chart.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hyperlink bar graph in highcharts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722043/how-to-hyperlink-bar-graph-in-highcharts)

Comment: I advice to familiar with drilldown option: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown