# Hyperlink bar chart in Highcharter

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I'm having trouble recreating [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722043/how-to-hyperlink-bar-graph-in-highcharts) in R with Highcharter to make the bars in a bar chart into clickable URLs. [Here is the Javascript code](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-point-events-click-url/) from the answer. Highcharter has a [vignette](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/highcharter/vignettes/replicating-highcharts-demos.html) about recreating Javascript that I tried to follow. Here's what tried so far. It doesn't show any of the bars.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)

highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
  hc_title(text = "Click points to go to URL") %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>%
  hc_plotOptions(series = list(cursor = "pointer"),
                 point =
                   list(events = list(
                     click = JS(
                       "function () {
                       location.href = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' +
                       this.options.key;
                       }"
                     )
                     ))) %>%
  hc_series(
    list(name = "USA", key = "United_States", y = 29.9),
    list(name = "Canada", key = "Canada", y = 71.5),
    list(name = "Mexico", key = "Mexico", y = 106.4)
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andrew,

You have some (2) errors replicating the example:

1. If you check carefully the example you gave. The `point` argument lives at the same depth of `cursor` in the `series` argument.
2. You didn't add the data in the correct way (like the vignette show).

A fixed version of your code is:

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
  hc_title(text = "Click points to go to URL") %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>%
  hc_plotOptions(
    series = list(
      cursor = "pointer",
      point = list(
        events = list(
          click = JS( "function () { location.href = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + this.options.key; }")
          )
        )
      )
    ) %>%
  hc_series(
    list(
      data = list(
        list(name = "USA", key = "United_States", y = 29.9),
        list(name = "Canada", key = "Canada", y = 71.5),
        list(name = "Mexico", key = "Mexico", y = 106.4)
        )
      )
  )
```

And a better version to add the data would be:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  country = c("USA", "Canada", "Mexico"),
  url = c("United_States", "Canada", "Mexico"),
  value = c(29.9, 71.5, 106.4)
)

highchart() %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>%
  hc_plotOptions(
    series = list(
      cursor = "pointer",
      point = list(
        events = list(
          click = JS( "function () { location.href = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + this.options.key; }")
          )
        )
      )
    ) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = dat, type = "column", mapping = hcaes(name = country, key = url, y = value))
```

Hope its helps

Comment: Thank you so much! Highcharter is such a great package!