# Adding a hyperlink to text or rectangle in barplot using R

Tags: r, hyperlink, bar-chart

I have a barplot which ONLY shows rectangles I have created using the rect function. In each rectangle I have added text using the text function. I would like to have a hyperlink for each rectangle (or by clicking on the text in the rectangle). I am not even sure if this is possible to do.

Below shows an example of my code...

```
plot(c(0, 420), c(0, 155), type= "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
rect(0, 0, 75, 75, col="tan1")
rect(0, 80, 75, 150, col="tan1")
rect(85, 0, 165, 75, col="tan1") 
rect(85, 80, 165, 150, col="tan1")
rect(175, 80, 250, 150, col="tan1")
text(38, 117, "One")
text(38, 40, "Two")
text(126, 117, "Three")
text(126, 40, "Four")
text(212, 117, "Five")
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: Here they discuss the issue: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/adding-hyperlinked-text-to-pdf-plot-td4161677.html

Comment: Take a look at either `plotly` or `highcharter` packages https://community.plot.ly/t/hyperlink-to-data-point/8320/2 | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48346042/hyperlink-bar-chart-in-highcharter